# How to export MobaXterm sessions to another computer?

Tags: mobaxterm

How can I export MobaXterm sessions to another computer?  There is mention of a MobaXterm.ini file, but I cannot locate that file using the documentation.

Comment: In my case it resides under C:/Users/[MyUser]/Documents/MobaXterm

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can do that with a right click on the "Saved Sessions" folder inside your "Sessions" tab. I think it is an easier and faster way to reach your goal.

[image]

Maybe these article on their official blog could be usefull too :
http://blog.mobatek.net/post/mobaxterm-configuration-settings/

Answer (score 15):

It depends on the version of MobaXterm you were using, but you can find the configuration file of MobaXterm that contains the session list ("MobaXterm.ini"). It is in the same folder than MobaXterm  executable or in "MyDocuments\MobaXterm" folder

Comment: cools thanks; do you know if that also exports all the marcos as well?

Comment: Just wanted to add... My previous install had a location of: C:\Users\\[User]\Documents\MobaXTerm\ and then on a new install of windows and mobaxterm it was located in: C:\Users\\[User]\AppData\Roaming\MobaXTerm\ so I assume the documents path was an earlier version and then it just got migrated when updating.  AppData version:23.2 and the Documents version: ???<23.2

Answer (score 6):

I have v8.6 on Windows 7 professional, and v10.2 on Windows 10 professional. 
The `MobaXterm.ini` file is located at
`C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MobaXterm`
on both machines, while the executable is at
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Mobatek\MobaXterm` as default.

Comment: Thank you! I needed to find MobaXterm.ini to mass delete old sessions. We changed a naming convention, so half of my sessions no longer actually worked.

Answer (score 3):

- in past versions: `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\MobaXterm`
- in current version as of 2020: `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\MobaXterm`
- what you should do: in mobaxterm >> `settings` >> `configuration` >>
  `tab: "general"` and choose your own proper location so you find it
  easier to access/edit in the future